# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. How to know to use word "key" instead of "key2"

Tags: reactjs

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.
In  key I use "key2" and get below error message. If I use "key" I don't get below error message.
How do you know to use the word "key" instead of "key2"?

```
Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

ImageList.js:

```js
import React from 'react';

const ImageList = (props) => {
  const images = props.images.map((image) => {
    return <img key2={image.id} src={image.urls.regular} />;
  });
  console.log(props.images);
  return <div>{images}</div>;
};

export default ImageList;
```

Answer (score 4):

From the React Doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

> A “key” is a special string attribute you need to include when creating lists of elements. Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity.

Learn more about it and how should you select your key attribute here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what @Nishant has figured out.

`Key`s are very important to decide the React’s “diffing” algorithm to when to re-render the view when data is changed.

> When you use React, at a single point in time you can think of the render() function as creating a tree of React elements. On the next state or props update, that render() function will return a different tree of React elements. React then needs to figure out how to efficiently update the UI to match the most recent tree.

> There are some generic solutions to this algorithmic problem of generating the minimum number of operations to transform one tree into another. However, the state of the art algorithms have a complexity in the order of O(n3) where n is the number of elements in the tree.

> If we used this in React, displaying 1000 elements would require in the order of one billion comparisons. This is far too expensive. Instead, React implements a heuristic O(n) algorithm based on two assumptions:

> Two elements of different types will produce different trees.
> The developer can hint at which child elements may be stable across different renders with a key prop.

[You can refer to this section from the docs to find out what exactly keys are used for](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys)

[You can refer to this docs for a deep understanding of how react's diffing algorithm works.](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html)

Answer (score 1):

you're using `key2` prop and it's correct to simply identify components(if your collection return components in `map()`). You must use key to help reconciliation React algorithm re-renders elements. It's not possible to use this props because it's inside of mechanism. Please use `key` with id for formally require and take other prop if you need. Good practice is not to use numbers in props btw.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless to `key2`, each element in array must contain `key` in JSX, like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const ImageList = props => {
  const images = props.images.map((image) => {
    return <img key={image.id} key2={image.id} src={image.urls.regular} />
    });
    console.log(props.images)
    return <div>{images}</div>;
}

export default ImageList;
```